# Parse.exe crashing and no creating necessary files

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to start learning parse cloud code. When I launch the parse.exe via my command line, various terrible things happen. For example, if I try to launch it using any kind of a command, but it's not set to "launch as administrator", I will see no text from the program(it will expect me to input my email and password, yet I will see no text I would see if I launched it as administrator). If I run it as administrator, it ends up consistently crashing during any activity. For example, if I try to go for >parse list, I will get to login, the list of apps appears and then the window instantly closes. Strictly following the tutorial(https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#cloud_code/windows) crashes midway as well. Doing >parse new for my existing app creates parse.local and parse.project files in the specified directory, but none of the rest files expected. I cannot seem to find the  I'm pretty much lost here. Am I doing something wrong? I have the latest parse.exe thing, redownloaded it from multiple locations provided by parse.

Comment: What version is it? What are the permissions on folders it's using? What system logs are there?

Comment: Parse.exe comes from a folder on the desktop, no custom permissions. It automatically creates files in C:\users\username. Parse CLI v3.0.2. System logs - never had to use those, if you give me a hint or two I will probably be able to tell.

Comment: I don't use windows, I'm just trying to get some more details someone else might find useful for diagnosis...